# Rstudio Server Run from specific directory

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am spinning up an instance of rstudio server and I need the working directory of R to be a specific directory. I would also like the file pane in the bottom right corner to be pointing to the same directory. Is there a way to do this? Currently it runs from the home directory of whichever user is running the program. I have tried the `--server-working-dir` flag, and it does not seem to work. Here is the command I am using:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver \
                         --server-daemonize=0 \
                         --server-user=user \
                         --server-working-dir=/some/path \
                         --auth-none=1 \
                         --auth-minimum-user-id=0
```

Any help would be useful here.

[edit] Just wanted to clarify that I would like the server to start in this directory. I am building a container that will be deployed multiple times, and I don't want the users to have to set their directories every time it is deployed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify the file pane in the right, you should edit `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf`.
 And add two lines in below:

```
session-default-working-dir=/some/path
session-default-new-project-dir=/some/path
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by edditing the (global) R profile startup script.  Here's a step by step guide:

1) Run `Rscript -e "R.home()"` -- this will tell you the location of your R directory home.  In my case (Mac) it is `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources`

2) Go to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc` -- e.g., `$R_HOME/etc`

3) `sudo touch Rprofile.site` if it doesn't exist, then `sudo nano Rprofile.site`

4) Add the following lines and save:

```
cat("hi\n")
setwd("/some/path/")
```

Comment: This does set the working directory but doesn't point the file pane to the right location. I wish I could give you half the bounty because apparently there is more than one `Rprofile.site` on the machine and I was editing the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid overwriting the users home directory.
Amongs the [.Rprofile] files you should only edit the Rprofile.site as a last resort since it acts globally.

**Suggested solution:**

R read the "initialization file" at start, in the following order:

- .Rprofile.site
- .Rprofile (located in the current directory).
- .Rprofile (in the users home directory).

In your case if you are planning to login to R-Studio server you will end up in the users home directory, so I would suggest you to just edit the [.Rprofile] in the home directory. In case the [.Rprofile] is missing you need to create it.

Add this line in your .Rprofile [in your home directory]:

```
setwd ('/your/path/')
```

Logout/login to your R-studio server session and you will notice that the "file pane to the right location" has changed accordingly to what you specified in your .Rprofile.